# **How to select specified number of IMG tags from quantity input value**

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, shopping-cart

**Image example:**

[image]

As you can see from clicking the image example link above, “EE” is the row and “8” is the item number.
I would like to select three of the following four IMG tag items located in the same row and echo the result.

```
<div id="surface" style="width: 4567px; height: 4137px; left: -1850px; top: -1152px; cursor: default;">


<img src="https://media.memories.png" data-items="L:106|EE:5" data-pl="1" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 14px; height: 14px; left: 2221px; top: 1561px; display: block;">


<img src="https://media.memories.png" data-items="L:106|EE:6" data-pl="1" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 14px; height: 14px; left: 2237px; top: 1561px; display: block;">


<img src="https://media.memories.png" data-items="L:106|EE:7" data-pl="1" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 14px; height: 14px; left: 2253px; top: 1561px; display: block;">


<img src="https://media.memories.png" data-items="L:106|EE:8" data-pl="1" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 14px; height: 14px; left: 2269px; top: 1561px; display: block;">


</div>
```

I figured out how to select one of the above img tags by specified row and item number using the following xpath, but how can select three items in the row “EE” after selecting the number 3 from a drop-down menu?

```
Xpath=//img[@data-items = ' L:106|EE:8']
```

Example Drop-down Menu:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Select Quantity</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Item Count</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#"> 1</a>
    <a href="#"> 2</a>
    <a href="#"> 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to select all **a** in dropdown content?

Comment: Which three items do you want to choose?

Comment: Hey @DebanjanB i want to choose 3 random consecutive items like 6,7 and 8 within the row mentioned above.Still trying to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Muzzamil , I wan to select 3 random consecutive items like 6,7 and 8 in the div i posted above after clicking the 3 button in my drop down example.The order does not matter as long as there consecutive numbers like 6,7,8 or 5,6,7.Hope that explains a bit more detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select `3` from the drop-down you can use the below xpath.

```
//div[@class='dropdown-content']/a[normalize-space(.)='3']
```

You can click on the `//button[.='Item Count']` and then use the xpath to select `3`.

Alternatively, you can use js to select `3` without clicking on the button.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown-content']/a[normalize-space(.)='3']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the post and effort!,  unfortunately this wont work for me as i'am trying to select 3 random consecutive items like 6,7 and 8 or 5,6 and 7 in the row as shown above in my post. The three selection from the drop down is only providing my input value .Hope this helps a little more in detail. Thank you guys! gonna keep looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `list` of all images and then iterate only 3 images using `sublist`. Please have a look on below code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
List<WebElement> allImages = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#surface > img"));
for (WebElement image : allImages.subList(1, allImages.size())) 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(image));
    image.click();
```

Comment: Hey Muzzamil this works great in Eclipse however i would like to get it to work in Selenium IDE.Some sites detect and prevent you from using web-driver. Would you be familiar on how to do this via IDE?

Comment: You should mention selenium Ide in tags and in question. For webdriver you can use proxy to access specific website.